Amazon S3 Lifecycle - Prefix setup
Bucket: testing-bucket
Folder: Examination
Sub-folder: Subjects
Sub-folders inside Subjects: English, Maths, Tamil

We have attached marksheets of 50 students under the above sub-folders: English, Maths, Tamil. Will upload all the marksheets on the same day.
I have created a lifecycle policy with prefix as "Examination/Subjects/". It should delete the files older than one month.
Expected outcome is that - It should delete sub-folders "English, Maths, Tamil" and its content (marksheet of 50 students).
But it is deleting the folder "Subjects".
What lifecycle prefix should I give for this requirement so that it will not delete this folder "Subjects" and delete only the sub-folders "English, Maths, Tamil" and its content which are older than a day.
